# When is the following summation is negative?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

We have $n$ children. We divide the children into two groups. One is of $m$ children(Group A) and the other one is the rest $n-m$(Group B). Now we will randomly give $t$ toys to $t$ children of the $n$ children(the $t$ children is randomly selected. Any one of the $t$ children receives only 1 toy). When Group A will have the greater possibility that receives odd toys than even?

The difference of receiving even and odd cases is following (even is positive and odd is negative):

$D(n,m,t)=\sum_{i=\max(0, t-(n-m))}^{\min(m,t)}(-1)^{i}\tbinom{m}{i}\tbinom{n-m}{t-i}$

**When $D(n,m,t)$ is negative?** That means Group A will have greater possibility that receives odd toys.

To simplify the problem, we can discuss the simplest case first: $0<m<=t<=n/2$. Then $D(n,m,t)=\sum_{i=0}^{m}(-1)^{i}\tbinom{m}{i}\tbinom{n-m}{t-i}$. It is little surprised that in small number numeric test using computer programs, $D(n,m,t)$ is "always" positive  (I have to admit that the test cases maybe not enough) though I used to think the sign should have *equal possibility*. Is the sign becomes negative only when $m$ is large enough (beyond $n/2$)?

Another way is to consider the result is $t$ degree coefficient of polynomial $(1-x)^m(1+x)^{n-m}$. But the coefficient sign is still difficult for estimate using derivative.

Thanks for any possible suggestion!